# .html returns undefined, but console.log correctly displays the element

Tags: jquery

I have a jQuery script that fetches results from the database, correctly, then displays the values in separate spans.

```
<div id="userTagsContainer" name="tagsPlaceholder" data-placeholder="Keywords" contenteditable>
</div>
<div id="exist-tags">
</div>
```

I simplified my HTML, and here is the jQuery.

```
$(function(){
$("#userTagsContainer").on('click',function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'tags.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(response){
            response = JSON.stringify(response);
            response = response.replace(/"/g,'');
            response = response.replace('[','');
            response = response.replace(']','');
            var tags = response.split(',');
            if($('#exist-tags').text().length == 0){
                for(var i=0;i<tags.length;i++){
                    $("#exist-tags").append('<span class="tag" id="tag'+i+'"></span>');
                    $('#tag'+i).html(tags[i]);
                }
            }
        },
        error: function(xhr) {
            alert("FAIL: "+xhr.status);
        }
    });
});
$("#exist-tags").on('click',function(e){
    if(e.target!=this){
        console.log(e.target);
        var clicked = (e.target).html;
        console.log(clicked);
        $("#userTagsContainer").append('<input class="tag" type="hidden" name="tagsList[]">'+clicked);
    }
});
});
```

In the last part, I have a div that contains the spans in pretty css boxes. If you click in one of the spans, it's supposed to insert its name into an editable div (think hashtags).
However, even though the console.log correctly displays the full element, including text/html, the .html method returns undefined. Any ideas?
EDIT: If you have a better method for fetching and stripping the results in order to present plain text to the user, let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`e.target` is a vanilla javascript DOM element, not a jquery object.
To get its HTML, you need to use [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML):

```
var clicked = (e.target).innerHTML;
```

There is also an `outerHTML` which generally works but is a bit non-standard, especially on older browsers.

If it were a jquery object, or you created one using `$(e.target)`, you can the [`html()`](https://api.jquery.com/html/) method to get the same.

```
var clicked = $(e.target).html();
```

Comment: It worked with the innerHTML method, thank you. But if I try the second method, I get a long string of functions, probably an exception. Needs some other modification or should work out of the box?

Answer (score 0):

You could change the click function to leverage jQuery:

```
    $("#exist-tags span.tag").on("click", function (e) {
        var clicked = $(this).html();
        console.log("=> " + clicked);
        $("#userTagsContainer").append('<input class="tag" type="hidden" name="tagsList[]">' + clicked);
    });
```